# How to customize a grouping value in ag-grid for a specific column?

Tags: ag-grid

I have an ag-grid enterprise component showing a list such as this:

```
Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
--------  --------  ----------
ABC123    4         Category 1
ABC456    5         Category 2
DEF789    1         Category 1
DEF012    8         Category 3
```

When the user choses to group the results by *Column 1*, I want ag-grid to use *only the first three letters* in order to perform the grouping, and not the full values:

```
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
   --------  --------  ----------
> ABC
   ABC123    4         Category 1
   ABC456    5         Category 2
> DEF
   DEF789    1         Category 1
   DEF012    8         Category 3
```

How do I do that?

From what I understand, [group cell renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-provided-renderer-group/) only affects the way groups are displayed, but doesn't change the actual values of the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I can use `keyCreator` to do exactly that:

```js
const colDef = [
    {
        headerName: 'Column 1',
        ...
        rowGroup: true,
        keyCreator: p => p.value.substr(0, 3)
    },
    ...
]
```